# How to assign a value to a selected element based on its index React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Expected effect: click `<li> </ li>` -> take index li -> share `index` and`this.state.todos` in the component `clock` -> on the basis of`index` select element from array -> assign to the selected element the value returned by `Math.random ()` ---> choose an adhesive element from the array -> assigns a different random value to it -> click on the previous element ---> display me assigned value for it.
In the console I have from `selectState` is undefined.
When I switch between `<li>` the index does not change. Ask for some advice.

**this.sate.selec move to component 'clock' and assign to this.state.selectTodo**

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        withInitialTodos: true,
        selec: null,
        todos: [
            {
                time: '00:00:10',
                description: 'Hello'
            },
            {
                time: '00:00:20',
                description: 'World'
            }
        ],
        todo: {
            'time': '00:00:30',
            'description': 'W'
        },
        selectTodo: {
            "times": [{ 'time': '00:00:40' }, { 'time': '00:00:50' }],
            "description": " ytytyty",
            "id": 3,
            "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"
        },
        saveTodo: {
            "time": '03:03:03'
        }
    };
  }

  selectTodo = (index) => {
    this.setState({
      selec: index
    })
  }

  createTodo = (todo) => {
    this.setState({
        withInitialTodos: false,
        todos: [].concat(this.state.todos, this.state.todo),
        selectTodo: {
            ...this.state.selectTodo,
            times: [].concat(
                this.state.selectTodo.times,
                this.state.withInitialTodos ? this.state.todos.map(({ time }) => ({ time })): [],
                {
                  time: this.state.todo.time
                }
            )
        }
    });
  }

  saveTodo = (description) => {
    const todo = {
      description,
      time: '03:03:03'
    };

    const todos = [].concat(this.state.todos, todo);

    this.setState({
      todos
    });
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.state.todos);
    console.log(this.state.selectTodo);
     console.log(this.state.selec);
     console.log("sdsd " + this.state.todos[this.state.selec])
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.todos
              .map((todo, index) =>
                <Todo
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  todo={todo}
                  selectTodo ={this.selectTodo}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.createTodo}>Add</button>


        <Clock
          todos={this.state.todos}
          selec={this.state.selec}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Todo**

```
class Todo extends Component {
  render () {
    {console.log(this.props.todo)};
    return (
      <li onClick={()=> this.props.selectTodo(this.props.index)}>
        {this.props.todo.description}
      </li>
    )
  } 
}

export default Todo;
```

**Clock**

```
class Clock extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      selectTodo: [],
      clock: Math.random()
    }
  }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectTodo: this.props.todos[this.props.selec]
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.selectTodo = this.state.clock}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pxjzb3

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. From what I understand the high level process.

User clicks on Select TODO
The TODO should be assigned a random clock value
Is that correct?

Comment: @ShivaPandey PandeyYes. When I click todo1 --assign random clock value; when I click todo2 --> assign random clock value. When I click again todo1 display previus value and add new random clock value to lists

Comment: So the idea is to show number of times user selected todo. And display all past clock times.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not correct. You need to understand and separate the components based on their behavior ( what they are supposed to do ). And state and props are passed from top to bottom. Keeping that in mind will be helpful in structuring the component hierarchy. In this case selectTodo function on Todo component should add the random clock value, because it is the most ideal position for that logic and the clock doesn't need to know anything if you want to display the list of previous random numbers or times. you just have to pass the selected component and it will render those information. You can refactor your code like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      { id: 0, times: ["00:00:10"], description: "some desc" },
      { id: 1, times: ["00:00:20"], description: "some desc1" }
    ],
    selectedIndex: null
  };

  createTodo = todo => {
    /** 
     * Create Todo Logic
    */
  }

  selectTodo = index => {
    let newTodos = [...this.state.todos]
    let newTime = Math.random();
    newTodos[index].times.push(newTime);
    this.setState({todos: newTodos, selectedIndex: index});
  }


  render() {
    <div>
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => (
            <Todo 
              key={todo.id}
              description={todo}
              onSelectTodo={() => this.selectTodo(index)}
            />
          ))
        }
      </ul>
      <Watch 
        todo={this.state.todos[this.state.selectedIndex]}
      />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Feel free to ask questions if you don't understand anything here.